# How to import the data from a data dump (SqLite3) into django?

Tags: mysql, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have a data dump file(.sql) containing certain data, I would like to import it to my database(currently Sqlite3 but thinking about changing to MySQL) in order to use it in my test website.
Also, I need to know if it's possible to add the models too automatically, I presume it needs to be added manually, but any how, if there is any way to solve it, please suggest it.

Comment: I don't understand the first question. For the second, see [the docs on legacy databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an alternative answer after researching a bit.
Since I'm having a PostgreSQL data dump file with a file extension '.sql', I was capable of running a single command that imported the whole data dump into my local database, which is PostgreSQL. I'm using PgAdmin4 as my database management system and I installed psql during the installation of PgAdmin4, I added the psql to the path of my command prompt, hence it was accessible.
In order to import the data dump, I used the command provided below,

```
psql -U <username> -d <database_name> < <file.sql>
```

The '<' after database_name is necessary, so be sure to include it.
Here  is the username of the configured account,  is the database to which the data dump should be added, , is the file containing the data dump.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) to help you generate the Django models automatically given you have an existing database.
However this is a shortcut. You may then fine tune your models and add them to your app as needed.

Structuring your models in apps might force you to use the Models [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#db-table) meta option.

If at some point you would like to switch databases (Sqlite3 -> MySQL) you can export (dump) your current data to json. Then you could import (load) the data to the new database (after creating the database tables with [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#migrate) command). To do this you can use Django management commands:

- [Dump data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)
- [Load data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)